# Search For Subtext In Text With A Defined Algorithm

Tags: c++, search

I want to create a program to search for a subtext in a text.

For example, I have this text: ab**cd**eabbdfeg

And in that text I want to find: **cd**

But I want to use this algorithm:

```
start = 1
end = string length of the text
middle = (start + end) / 2
if (pattern < text[middle])  end = mid - 1;
if (pattern > text[middle]) start = mid + 1;
...and continue until the pattern is found in the text
```

So, I already have a simple program that completely works without any problem but without that algorithm above, so now I only want to implement that algorithm above in my program, I have tried many ways, but my program won't show anything in any case, after I add that algorithm...

This is the code that I have and works:

```
void search(char *pat, char *txt)
{
    int M = strlen(pat);
    int N = strlen(txt);

    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++)
    {
        int j;

        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            if (txt[i+j] != pat[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j == M)
        {
           printf("Pattern found at index %d \n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code above with the implementation of the algorithm:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char t[32];
    cout << "Please enter your text (t):";
    cin >> t;

    char p[32];
    cout << "Please enter the pattern (p) you wish to look for in that text (t):";
    cin >> p;


    int start, end = 0;
    double middle = 0;
    start = 1;
    end = strlen(t);


        while (start <= end)
        {
            int M = strlen(p);
            int N = strlen(t);


            middle = std::ceil((start + end) / 2.0);
            int mid = (int)middle;
            for (int i = mid; i <= M; i++)
            {

                int j;


                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                {
                    if (t[mid] != p[j]) break;
                    if (p[j] < t[mid])  { end = mid - 1; }
                    else if (p[j] > t[mid]) { start = mid + 1; }
                }


                if (j == M)
                {
                    printf("Pattern found at index %d \n", i);
                }
            }
        }
        if (start > end) cout << "Search has ended: pattern p does not occur in the text." << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Typically in C++ you'd use the `<string>` classes for strings, among other things.

Comment: I don't understand how you can tell which partition to choose since the collection is not sorted.

Comment: What is the objective of your assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is still a binary search.  You split the array into two partitions, then select a partition, **based on the value of a letter**.

The requirements of a partitioned search is to have an ordered collection.

Let's use your example.

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9   10  11  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+  
| a | b | c | d | e | a | b | b | d | f | e | g |  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you choose the midpoint at index 5, this yields the letter `a`.  Since you are searching for the letter `c` first, then `d`, the algorithm says that the letter `c` must lie in the partition 6..11.  Thus the basis of your issue.

The algorithm will not find `cd` because there is no `c` in the partition 6..11.

**The algorithm assumes that the array is sorted and that for any given index, there will be one partition containing values less than array[index] and one partition containing values greater than array[index].**

This assumption is demonstrated by the following code of yours:

```
            if (p[j] < t[mid])  { end = mid - 1; }
            else if (p[j] > t[mid]) { start = mid + 1; }
```

No matter how you name your algorithm, if it assumes an ordering on the array (e.g. `p[j] < t[mid]`), the **array must be ordered.**

You data is not ordered, so your algorithm fails the assumption, and thus the algorithm fails.

**Edit 1:**

### Using Partitions

If you really *must* use a partitioning algorithm, you will need to build a set of partitions.
For example one partition starts at index 0 and proceeds until array[i] > array[i+1], this ends up at index 4.  The other partition is 5..11.

*(By the way, by determining the partitions, you have used more operations than a linear search.)*

At this point, how do you know which partition to choose?

You don't.  The letter `c`, that you are searching for, lies between `a` and `e` in the first partition; and `a` through `g` in the second partition.  Pick a partition.  If not found in the partition, you will have to search the other partition.

By performing a binary search on either partition, you have used more operations than a linear search.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the data?  Sorting will destroy any sequences.  You can use `std::sort`.  A linear search will be faster than sorting and then using a binary search.  For a binary search, use these functions: `std::upper_bound`, `std::lower_bound`, or `std::binary_search`.

Comment: The best way is to talk with the customer or instructor or the person that gave you the requirements.  Tell them that a binary search only works on sorted data and in order to use the binary search, the data must be ordered which may changed the sequence of letters and their locations within the container.  In general, binary searches are not used to find text strings.